# How to continue saving to an existing m3u8 playlist using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, rtmp

I'm using nginx rtmp module to run a live streaming server that encodes a rtmp stream to a hls playlist. Is there a way to continue with an existing m3u8 file instead of creating a new playlist when I start ffmpeg? Streams can be disconnected sometimes and I want to keep a single playlist when a user resumes streaming.

Here's ffmpeg command I'm running:
`ffmpeg -i rtmp://localhost/live/$name -c:v libx264 -x264opts keyint=60:no-scenecut -s 720x1280 -r 30 -b:v 2000k -profile:v high -preset veryfast -c:a libfdk_aac -sws_flags bilinear -hls_list_size 0 /tmp/hls/$name_720p_.m3u8`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the flag "append_list" to the directive hls_flags:

```
ffmpeg -i in.nut -hls_flags append_list out.m3u8
```

for more information:
https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html

Answer (score 1):

Use `hls_cleanup off` directive which in this case it won't remove old hls fragments and files, but you must use nginx rtmp hls instead of creating it with ffmpeg.

Answer (score 1):

There is an option `append_list`, whose explanation reads: "append the new segments into old hls segment list". It might work for you.